# If $x^{100}$ is 31 digit number Then $x^{1000}$ contains how many digits.

Tags: number-theory

If $x^{100}$ is 31 digit number Then $x^{1000}$ contains how many digits.

Our Approach:

$10^1$ has $2$ digits = $10$

$10^2$ has $3$ digits = $100$

$10^3$ has $4$ digits = $1000$

$10^{30}$  has  $31$ digits

therefore, $10^{30}=x^{100}$

$30 = 100\log x$

multiplying both sides by $10$

$30 \cdot 10 = 10 \cdot 100\log x$

$300 = 1000\log x = 300+1=301$

so $301$ is correct answer

> Q Any other approach to solve this problem and Also correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are stating that two numbers are equal when you don't know that. A two digit number has $10\le x \lt100$ so that $1\le \log x \lt 2$ so you have to work with inequalities, and you will find that just as $10^2=100$ has three digits and $99^2=9801$ has four digits, you will not have a definite answer, but a range of possibilities.

Comment: Where i am stating that? Please Explain

Comment: Is $x$ an integer, or can it be any number?

Comment: Using Logarithms you can find that the number of digits is in the range :[320,330] perhaps there's a tighter bound

Comment: "Therefore, $10^{30}=x^{100}$" is problematic

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, you don't get a range of possibilities, you get a single answer.

Comment: @columbus8myhw great observation - I put up an answer, but deleted it. The answer is not $301$ digits, but requires more accurate analysis.

Comment: @Mark, your answer was correct if you add integer condition. Why you deleted it?

Comment: @hvedrung I felt it gave too much information to someone who probably needed to think it through a bit to understand the issue.

Comment: @MarkBennet Please Explain where u showed me  that the 2 numbers are equal?

Comment: @columbus8myhw $x$^$31$ is given a 31 digit number so i substituted it.

Comment: Where @columbus8myhw says you did it - where you put "=" the first time with $x$ in the equation. There are lots of 31 digit numbers, and if you are looking for $x$ to be an integer then $10^{0.3}$ is not an integer - but you can find an integer that will do. If you are looking for $x^{100}$ to be an integer, you get a range for $x^{1000}$.

Comment: @justintakro The problem is that there's more than one 31-digit number. Just because $x^{31}$ is 31-digit and $10^{30}$ is 31-digit doesn't mean $x^{31}=10^{30}$. (That's like saying that, since $12$ is 2-digit and $32$ is 2-digit, we have $12=32$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw you are right we will not get a number but a range of numbers of 31 digit as pointed out by MarkBennet first.But we should only care about how many digit number a number can have rather than comparing relatively with 12 and 32.So from my point of you that statement also cannot be ruled out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^{100}$ is 31 digit => $$10^{30}\leq x^{100}< 10^{31} \Rightarrow 10^{300}\leq x^{1000}< 10^{310}.$$ This means that $x^{1000}$ has from 301 t0 310 digits.

Comment: Your inequalities don't make sense as written, i.e. $10^{31} < 10^{30}$ and $10^{310} < 10^{300}$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^{100}$ is a $31$ digit number, we have $10^{30}\le x^{100}\lt 10^{31}$

Taking logarithms we then have $30\le 100 \log x \lt 31$ so that $0.3\lt \log x \lt 0.31$

If $x$ is an integer, then $x=2$.

You should be able to complete the question from there. Logarithms are taken to base ten.

Comment: I could not understand from where u told.Why x cannot be 3,4?What value you got i cannot think that much.

Comment: @justintakro $\log 3 \approx 0.477 \gt 0.31$ so that $3^{100}$ has more than $31$ digits.

Comment: Why is $x$ an integer?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I did note "if" - sometimes questions like this make implicit assumptions. If you look at the comments to the question, I deleted this previously, but some commentators wanted it reinstated. So I put it back up because it seemed to be useful.